# Issue with Full Outer Join

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update a query that is joining TT and HR tables:

[image: TT and HR tables]
The current result is:

[image: Current Result]

I want my result table to include all records from TT table.

The expected result should be:

[image: Expected Result]

My current query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
TT.Month,
TT.Mapping_ID,
HR.Employee_ID,
HR.Month,
ISNULL(SUM(TT.Hours), 0) AS Hours
HR.Source
FROM TT FULL OUTER JOIN HR ON TT.Month = HR.Month AND TT.Mapping_ID IN (HR.Employee_ID, HR.ID2, HR.ID3, HR.ID3, HR.ID4, HR.ID5, HR.ID6)
WHERE  HR.Month='10/1/2019'
GROUP BY TT.Month, TT.Mapping_ID, HR.Employee_ID, HR.Month, HR.Source
```

Does anybody have a suggestion how to update the SQL?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vaxDCNm3ZQ9gv5FZtjBAV2/1

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause literally filter out all rows what has `NULL` values for your column `HR.Month`.  Put your `WHERE` in `ON` clause instead.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
TT.Month,
TT.Mapping_ID,
HR.Employee_ID,
HR.Month,
ISNULL(SUM(TT.Hours), 0) AS Hours
HR.Source
FROM TT FULL OUTER JOIN HR ON TT.Month = HR.Month AND TT.Mapping_ID IN (HR.Employee_ID, HR.ID2, HR.ID3, HR.ID3, HR.ID4, HR.ID5, HR.ID6) AND HR.Month='10/1/2019'
GROUP BY TT.Month, TT.Mapping_ID, HR.Employee_ID, HR.Month, HR.Source
```

Comment: Ninja'd while I was composing a response. :)  I'm not 100% sure this will work though? I'd like to see an SQLFiddle (or whatever site is supporting SQL properly these days)

Comment: The initial query returns the result in 25 seconds. The suggested change has not yet provided the result after 15 minutes execution.

Comment: Hi Ross, I am not sure how to replicate FULL OUTER JOIN with MySQL but I create the example with RIGHT JOIN. The SQLDBFiddle can be found here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vaxDCNm3ZQ9gv5FZtjBAV2/1